# Adding properties to output of current_principal_details() in Azure Data Explorer

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I am implementing Row Level Security in Azure Data Explorer, I am using

```
  current_principal_details()
```

To get information about the user but how can I add the names of the groups or something that the user is part of?

I cannot use

```
current_principal_is_member_of()
```

Since I will have over 6000 groups and the RLS query will be just too long so my idea is to add groups or roles or something to the user that I can see using

```
current_principal_details()
```

And the parse them and use that as input to the RLS query

I am using the following KUSTO to get the info of the user

```
print d=current_principal_details()
```

I just need to know how to add properties to the output and use them as input to RLS query

Comment: Hey Matt, not sure I get the issue. Could you guide me here?

Comment: I wanted to add Group Memberships to the result so I could see what groups are available instead of checking each one by one, but I ended up solving this with a user mapping table instead which scales and works perfectly